# BIRT Viewer with Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting, birt

Has anyone tried using BIRT for reporting on a Rails app.. I am working on a pretty big app on ROR. I was trying to get BIRT to work happily with the app. Since the BIRT Report Designer cannot be used with Rails, I decided to use BIRT Viewer alone and give the links to the reports on the page and have BIRT Viewer running on Tomcat on the same box to render the reports. This has a big problem of not being able to allow the user to create any custom reports.

Has anybody tried anything even remotely close to this???

If yes do you have any tips for me on any part of this endeavor?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?  I'm looking into it with Python / Jython and Django

Answer (score 1):

I have tried but did not have any problem including the columns to create a customized report.